# Modifying a spark dataframe column

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark dataframe and I want to add a new column with some specific value. I have tried using withcolumn function but it is not working as expected. I want a new column with specific value or I want to replace an existing column

Comment: Please share example data, attempted code and expected output.

Comment: I have some property id's and some parameters. I have to give badges for the properties based on the parameters. I have found the properties which should be given the badges. It is stored in a dataframe. Now I have to add the column badge with some constant values. So my output will be like property Id with badge

Comment: please illustrate with example

Answer (score 0):

See this example

I have a dataFrame:

```
>>> df.show()
+-------+----+-----+---+
|   name|year|month|day|
+-------+----+-----+---+
|    Ali|2014|    9|  1|
|  Matei|2015|   10| 26|
|Michael|2015|   10| 25|
|Reynold|2015|   10| 25|
|Patrick|2015|    9|  1|
+-------+----+-----+---+
```

I want to add a information for each row, I can use `lit` to do that

```
>>> from pyspark.sql.functions import lit
>>> df.withColumn('my_new_column', lit('testing info for all')).show()
+-------+----+-----+---+--------------------+
|   name|year|month|day|       my_new_column|
+-------+----+-----+---+--------------------+
|    Ali|2014|    9|  1|testing info for all|
|  Matei|2015|   10| 26|testing info for all|
|Michael|2015|   10| 25|testing info for all|
|Reynold|2015|   10| 25|testing info for all|
|Patrick|2015|    9|  1|testing info for all|
+-------+----+-----+---+--------------------+
```

If you want to add a list of different information for each row you can use `explode`:

```
>>> from pyspark.sql.functions import explode
>>> df.withColumn('my_new_column', 
...               explode(array(lit('testing info for all'), 
...                             lit('other testing again')))).show()
+-------+----+-----+---+--------------------+
|   name|year|month|day|       my_new_column|
+-------+----+-----+---+--------------------+
|    Ali|2014|    9|  1|testing info for all|
|    Ali|2014|    9|  1| other testing again|
|  Matei|2015|   10| 26|testing info for all|
|  Matei|2015|   10| 26| other testing again|
|Michael|2015|   10| 25|testing info for all|
|Michael|2015|   10| 25| other testing again|
|Reynold|2015|   10| 25|testing info for all|
|Reynold|2015|   10| 25| other testing again|
|Patrick|2015|    9|  1|testing info for all|
|Patrick|2015|    9|  1| other testing again|
+-------+----+-----+---+--------------------+
```